# PFObject not being casted into Subclass

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, parse-platform, subclassing

*subclasses are registered in my app delegate

Users can create `classroom` objects. The problem is when a new `classroom` object is created, a following query will read the newest `classroom` as a `PFObject`. This will crash the program.

Previously made `classrooms` will be correctly read.

Also - when I close the app and restart it, the newest classroom is properly read as a `classroom`. How can I cast the newly created classroom into the right subclass?

The error received is:

```
    fatal error: NSArray element failed to match the Swift Array Element type
```

Thanks!

Class code for `classroom` object:

```
    class Classroom: PFObject, PFSubclassing{

var professorLastName: String?
var classTitle: String?
var toSchool: School?
var subjectLevel: String?
var subject: String?
var enrolledUsers: [PFUser]?

//THIS IS FOR CREATING A NEW CLASS
func enrollClass(){
    let classroom = PFObject(className: "Classroom")

    classroom["subject"] = self.subject
    ...


    classroom.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        print("added student to class.")
    }
} 

    //start protocol code for PFSubclass
static func parseClassName() -> String {
    return "Classroom"
}

override class func initialize() {
    var onceToken : dispatch_once_t = 0;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken) {
        self.registerSubclass()
    }
}
//end
```

This is the QUERY that pulls classrooms from Parse database and puts it into table view row cells:

QUERY:

```
    let query = PFQuery(className: "_User")
    query.includeKey("enrolledClasses")
    query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(PFUser.currentUser()!.objectId!) {(result:PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        let userEnrolledClasses = result!["enrolledClasses"] as! [Classroom]
        completionBlock(userEnrolledClasses)
```

Insertion into row cell:

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("enrolledClassCell") as! EnrolledClassesTableViewCell

    //THE CODE CRASHES HERE!!!! 
    let classroom = timelineComponent.content[indexPath.row] as? Classroom
    //NSARRAY FAILED TO MATCH ARRAY TYPE -> It's still PFObject



    classroom?.setClass()
    cell.enrolledOption.text = classroom?.classTitle
    return cell
}
```

Readout: 
[image]

AppDelegate:

```
    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    Classroom.registerSubclass()
    School.registerSubclass()
    Post.registerSubclass()
    PostPoints.registerSubclass()
    ReplyPost.registerSubclass()
    ReplyPostPoints.registerSubclass()
    SubjectList.registerSubclass()

    Parse.enableLocalDatastore()
```

**New code as per Daniel's fix...

So the objects are being read as `classroom` but now the attempt to pull data out of classroom objects is not work. So I want to set a label to be the `classroom.classTitle` for a table row, but the data is always nil...

```
    //TIMELINE IMPLEMENTATION
func loadInRange(range: Range<Int>, completionBlock: ([Classroom]?) -> Void) {
    Classroom.registerSubclass()

    let query = PFQuery(className: "_User")
    query.includeKey("enrolledClasses")
    query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(PFUser.currentUser()!.objectId!) {(result:PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        let rawPFObject = result!["enrolledClasses"] as! [PFObject]
        var classroomArray: [Classroom] = []

        for rawClassroom in rawPFObject{
            let convertedClassroom = Classroom()
            convertedClassroom.classTitle = rawClassroom["classTitle"] as? String
            convertedClassroom.subject = rawClassroom["subject"] as? String
            convertedClassroom.professorLastName = rawClassroom["professorLastName"] as? String
            convertedClassroom.subjectLevel = rawClassroom["classTitle"] as? String
            classroomArray.append(convertedClassroom)
        }

        completionBlock(classroomArray)

    }
}
```

LABEL ASSIGNMENT:

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("enrolledClassCell") as! EnrolledClassesTableViewCell
    //the tableViewCell post is equal to the post[arrayNumber]
    let classroom = timelineComponent.content[indexPath.row] as? Classroom
    //CLASSROOM VALUES ARE ALL NIL HERE
    classroom?.setClass()
    cell.enrolledOption.text = classroom?.classTitle
    return cell
}
```

Console readout:

[image]

Maybe it has to do with objectId being "new"?

Readout of `timelineComponent.content`

[image]

Comment: Add description and creation of `timelineComponent.content`

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're having is that casting to an array of `Classroom` is not working correctly in your query. This may be a shortcoming of Parse object subclasses.

A workaround is to create a temporary array that will be passed to completionBlock.

In this temporary array will be added `Classroom` objects that are explicitly created as a Parse subclass.

In your Classroom class, add:

```
func loadFromObject(object: PFObject) {
    // Setup a Classroom object from a PFObject.

    self.subject = object["subject"]

   ...
}
```

In your query, replace these lines

```
let userEnrolledClasses = result!["enrolledClasses"] as! [Classroom]
completionBlock(userEnrolledClasses)
```

with

```
var classroomArray = Array<Classroom>()

for class in result!["enrolledClasses"] {
    let newClass = Classroom().loadFromObject(class)
    classroomArray.append(newClass)
}

completionBlock(classroomArray)
```

Comment: Hi Daniel, your solution works but now I ran into another bug!

Comment: @MichaelNinh Is your `timelineComponent.content` an array containing `Classroom` objects? I can't see what type it is supposed to be from your code.

Comment: Yep, the last screen shot are the contents of `timelineComponent.content`. It's filled with `classroom` objects but their values are all nil

Comment: What if you remove the cast by `as? Classroom`? You shouldn't need to cast an object to its own type.

Comment: could it be that this PFObject is just not completely saved yet?